# Passing function to create new component to child using react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that consists of an array of SVG arrows, like this

```
const App = () => {
     const [arrows, createArrow]=useState([<Arrow x="7" y="100"/>,
     <Arrow x="50" y="100"/>])
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>createArrow([...arrows, <Arrow x="75" y="100"/>])}>Add Force</button> 
 
        <ArrowForm newArrow = {createArrow} arrows = {arrows}/>
   
      
      <svg
        style={{
          border: '1px solid green',
          height: '200px',
          width: '100%',
        }}
      >
          <Grid/>
          {arrows.map((child) => child)}
      </svg>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I'd like to set the position of the arrow using a form component, which I've created like this:

```
export default function ArrowForm({newArrow, arrows}) {
    const[position, setPosition] = useState({x:1, y:0})
    return(
        <div>
        <label>x: 
        <input type="number" value = {position.x} onChange={e=>setPosition(e.target.value)}/>
        </label>
        <label>y: 
        <input type="number" value = {position.y} onChange={e=>setPosition(e.target.value)}/>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onSubmit= ()=> {newArrow([...arrows, <Arrow x="75" y="100"/>])} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I think I need to pass the arrows state and createArrow function from the App form so that I can create arrows when I press the submit button in the form, but I'm getting a Maximum Update Depth exceeded error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in your `ArrowForm`

```
        <input type="submit" 
value="Submit" 
onSubmit= {newArrow([...arrows, <Arrow x="75" y="100"/>])} />
```

it means as  soon as your component render call `onSubmit` instead you have to do this:

```
<input
        type="submit"
        value="Submit"
        onSubmit={() => newArrow([...arrows, <div x="75" y="100" />])}
      />
```

Here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-euler-23dz9?file=/src/App.js:545-676). See console. As I don't know what is your arrow component do.

Comment: Thanks! Adding the arrow function did clear up the maximum update error, but it's still not adding arrow objects to the state. I also checked your demo, and the behavior is the same. Clicking submit doesn't add any divs to the arrow state.

Comment: Ahh my bad I copy paste your code. `onSubmit ` only works with `form` you need to replace with `onClick`. If you want to still use `onSubmit` wrap with `<form>`. Updated my example

Answer (score 1):

[@Shubham Verma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64657499/7064030) answer is correct, but you and he/she missed that input doesn't have `onSubmit` property, it is `form` that does.
So you should use `onClick`.

Here is the sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-surf-xb1h1